# display posts, categories, pages together - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm collecting statistics and there I want to show all pages, posts, taxonomy categories I have.

I could display post types and pages because actually they all have some post type but can't display taxonomy categories together with them:

```
<?php 
    $excluded_ids = array(1, 5);
    $postArgs = array(
        'post_type' => array('page', 'products'),
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'post__not_in' => $excluded_ids,
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        /*'taxonomy' => 'product-category'*/
    );
    $postList = get_posts($postArgs);
?>
```

Is there a way to display everything (posts,categories,pages) via single query and not multiple? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) method doesn't accept array as the post_type value. You should use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters) to query the posts.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'page', 'products'  )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understanded you correctly

```
$argss = array(
'post_type' => array('page', 'products'),
'order' => 'ASC',
'orderby' => 'title',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'your taxonomies',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'your term',
    ),
),
);

$the_queryy = new WP_Query( $argss );

if ( $the_queryy->have_posts() ) {
while ( $the_queryy->have_posts() ) {
    $the_queryy->the_post();
                      // echo stuff
}
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it is not working. It displays pages, products but not categories. @Tauras